# Why can't GridView perform update function on being databinded to an ObjectDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, data-binding

I followed this [awesome tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/continuing-with-ef/using-the-entity-framework-and-the-objectdatasource-control,-part-1-getting-started) when I needed to get kickstarted with ASP.NET! Accordingly, I started making a web app for a store! I started to code to store an ItemGroup which contains just two properties Name and Remark,both String! Entity Framework has been used. The validation code has been performed with the use of DataAnnotation as follow -

```
namespace StoreAppWeb.DAL
{
   [MetadataType(typeof(ItemGroupMetaData))]
   public partial class ItemGroup
  {
  }

public class ItemGroupMetaData
{

    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name of Item Group must be 100 characters or less.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name of Item Group is missing!")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

Realizing the importance of Persistence Ignorance, DAL and BLL has been implemented via the repository pattern. Then, the ItemGroupMgmtPage has been created whose main purpose is to add, delete and update the ItemGroup! Databinding though ObjectDataSource has been used. Everything works fine except the 'Updating' action! The portion of the code that really concerned here are posted here. The portion of ItemGroupBL class that really concerns here is -

```
namespace StoreAppWeb.BLL
{
    public class ItemGroupBL : IDisposable
    {
        private bool disposedValue = false;

        private IItemGroupRepository itemGroupRepository;

        public ItemGroupBL()
        {
            this.itemGroupRepository = new ItemGroupRepository();
        }

        //Other Functionality methods went here



        public void UpdateItemGroup(ItemGroup itemGroup, ItemGroup origItemGroup)
        {
            if(!itemGroup.Name.Equals(origItemGroup.Name))
                validateSingleItemGroup(itemGroup);
            try
            {
                itemGroupRepository.UpdateItemGroup(itemGroup, origItemGroup);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }



        private void validateSingleItemGroup(ItemGroup itemGroup)
        {
            var duplicateItemGroup = itemGroupRepository.GetItemGroupByName(itemGroup.Name);
            if (duplicateItemGroup != null)
            {
                throw new DuplicateItemGroupException(String.Format("ItemGroup {0}     already exists!", itemGroup.Name));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And the portion of the ItemGroupMgmtPage that really concerned here is given as -

```
<h2>
    Edit the Available Item Group List:
</h2>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ItemGroupObjectDataSourceForInsert" runat="server"         TypeName="StoreAppWeb.BLL.ItemGroupBL"
    DataObjectTypeName="StoreAppWeb.DAL.ItemGroup"
    SelectMethod="GetItemGroups" UpdateMethod="UpdateItemGroup"     DeleteMethod="DeleteItemGroup"
    ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" OldValuesParameterFormatString="orig{0}">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewItemGroupEdit" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataSourceID="ItemGroupObjectDataSourceForInsert" DataKeyNames="ID" AllowPaging="True"
    AllowSorting="true" OnRowDataBound="GridViewItemGroupEdit_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="Remark" HeaderText="Remark" SortExpression="Remark" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ItemGroupValidationSummary" runat="server" ShowSummary="true"
    DisplayMode="BulletList" />
```

I am unable to perform the update but rather get this -

[image]

Any clue why?

Answer (score 1):

While following the tutorial, you missed some part of `Update`. You need to add `EditItemTemplate`s like this:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemark" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Remark")%>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: thanx afzalulh,
ofc I have though of similar solution but in that tutorial, they have done editing w/o using the EditTemplate, is not it possible to perform the update function in that way?

Comment: No, in that tutorial they have used edititemtemplate. But they used dropdownlist instead of textbox.Please check the update part in the tutorial again!

Comment: yes its true that they have used dropdownlist insted of textbox for the department, but only for the adminstrator, but they have still used the <asp:DynamicField> for the Name and Budget of the Departments. Please check that second last image of the tutorial, clearly the first two field are not dropdownlist!

Comment: FYI @afzalulh, 
You can use DynamicField instead of TemplateField and ASP.NET knows what controls to use based on the data type of the field. You only use EditItemTemplate for TemplateField.
As mentioned in the comment section situated at the end of the tutorial which I was following!

Comment: Yes, you are right! However, I couldn't reproduce the issue. If this is a test project, you can send me the project so that I can look at it. Also, I would probably debug and see where the name is getting emptied.